Is it possible to build a virtual keyboard with Electron to use on a Kiosk?
So I'm developing a webapp that will be on a Kiosk (those stand displays that people can interact with using a touch screen). The thing is, this webapp has an Iframe with text fields. And I need the user to be able to write on them. If I use a virtual keyboard library, I have no way of sending the keystrokes to the Iframe (since it's hosted on another origin).
I though of building an Electron app that is a virtual keyboard that interacts directly with the computer so it's like having an actual keyboard being pressed. Is this possible to do with Electron? To emulate actual hardware keyboard presses?
